How to get wallet balance From SOLANA?
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';

const Hero = () => {
 const wallet = useWallet();
 const [rotateDeg, setRotateDeg] = useState(3);
 const [balance, setBalance] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
     const handleScroll = () => {
         const rotation = Math.max(Math.min(window.scrollY / 10, 10), 3);
         setRotateDeg(rotation);
     };

     window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
     return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
     const getBalance = async () => {
         if (wallet.connected && wallet.publicKey) {
             const connection = new Connection('https://rpc.ankr.com/solana');
             
             try {
                 // Ensure wallet.publicKey is a PublicKey instance before calling getBalance.
                 const publicKey = new PublicKey(wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
                 const balance = await connection.getBalance(publicKey);
                 setBalance(balance / 1e9); // Convert lamports to SOL
             } catch (error) {
                 console.error('Error getting balance:', error);
                 setBalance(null);
             }
         }
     };

     getBalance();
 }, [wallet.connected, wallet.publicKey]);

And im getting error:
StructError: Expected the value to satisfy a union of type | type, but received: [object Object]
Any ideas?
